# Import email addresses to Hotmail contacts without inviting as friends

Tags: outlook.com, contacts, import

I'm trying to set up a group of contacts in Hotmail with an imported list of email addresses.

Under Contacts there is a manage menu that has an Import option. However, that lets me import a list of addresses as live.com friends (it shows the invite people page and will send out an invitation email to each address).

I don't want these people to be live.com friends. I just want a list of email addresses I can treat as a group.

Are my only options to:

1. Add each email address manually as a new contact?
2. Use a different email service or listsrv?

Answer (score 5):

You can import contacts as a .csv file following the instructions here;

http://help.live.com/help.aspx?project=mailfull&market=en-us&querytype=topic&query=wl_mail_proc_importer.htm

1. Sign in to the Windows Live Hotmail website with your Windows Live ID.
2. In the upper-right corner of the page, click Options, and then click More options.
3. Under Customize your contacts, click Import contacts.
4. Select the e-mail program or service that you want to import your contacts from.
5. To find the file that you want to import, click Browse.
6. Locate the file, and then click Open.
7. Click Import contacts.

Hope this helps.